# How do I create a Android app using geofence in which when the user reaches the destination it automatically get rewards without doing anything?

Tags: android, geolocation, geofencing, android-geofence

I thought of sending location based push notification which when clicked give the person points https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/location-triggered-event in that case if notification were cleared the person will not get reward, how can i give the person reward automatically when he reaches the destination.

Answer (score 0):

Android's LocationManager allows your app to register for Proximity Alerts.  When the device enters a geographic location of interest (as defined by your app), your app will be notified via an intent sent to a BroadcastReceiver in your app.

Details: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert(double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative you can use is this, https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing . Note that it has a 100 geofence limit.